# How to modify the value of a variable whose name is given

Tags: ruby

I wish to have a method that takes in a string, and then updates a variable with the name of that string. This is an example of my attempt:

```
@other_class = OtherClass.new()

def change_variable(variable_string)
  self.@other_class.send.variable_string += 1
end
```

I am getting the error:

> syntax error, unexpected tIVAR

with the pointer just before 'send' in the method above. Does anyone have any suggestions to make this work?

Comment: Is `varaible_string` representing an instance variable?

Comment: use either `self` or `@` not `self.@....`

Comment: Not sure what you want, but remove `self`

Comment: A minor style point - Ruby's classes are also objects, so a name like @other_class may prove confusing to other readers and even yourself when you come back to your code in future.

Comment: Thank you - I simply used that name as an example, but I take your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate syntatic error is that you're using `self` and `@` wrongly.

Either one is fine but not in conjunction with each other.

So in your case `self.other_class.send...` would be fine but then you cant declare it as `@`.
As would `@` be but then you cant do `self`.

These are meant to do different things and these are that

`@` is an instance variable and so is `self` but the difference is that using `@` calls the attribute `other_class` directly as to where `self` calls the method `other_class`.

So `@` is both a getter and setter in one so you can do

`@other_class = my_milk_man` as to where

`self.other_class` `->` `self.other_class (as getter)`,

`self.other_class = my_milk_man` -> `self.other_class= (as setter)`.

Comment: Thank you - this is what fixed it.  I had just assumed that the error was related to the way I was using the variable name - I should have trusted Ruby more!

Answer (score 2):

You probably want instance_variable_set http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set

The syntax using your variables is I think:

```
other_var = ('@' + variable_string).to_sym

@other_class.instance_variable_set( other_var, @other_class.instance_variable_get( other_var ) + 1 )
```